# Try to optimize/improve my query, where I bring the number of orders and a column for each filter that I apply

Tags: sql, performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization

I'm trying to get the number of orders for different businesses

So, I have two tables:

*Table1:*

| Order_Number | Order_Date | Store_ID | Customer_ID | Is_Valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 55 | 25 | Valid |
| 2 | 24-05-2020 | 90 | 34 | Invalid |
| 3 | 03-09-2021 | 56 | 25 | Valid |
| 4 | 04-10-2021 | 210 | 100 | Invalid |

*Table2:*

| Order_Number | Order_Date | Store_ID | Customer_ID | Is_Valid | Product | IIM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 55 | 25 | Valid | Coca-Cola | False |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 55 | 25 | Valid | some drink | False |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 55 | 25 | Valid | some drink | True |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 55 | 25 | Valid | some drink | True |
| 2 | 24-05-2020 | 90 | 34 | Invalid | some drink | False |
| 3 | 03-09-2021 | 56 | 25 | Valid | some drink | True |
| 3 | 03-09-2021 | 56 | 25 | Valid | some drink | True |
| 4 | 04-10-2021 | 210 | 100 | Invalid | some drink | True |
| 4 | 04-10-2021 | 210 | 100 | Invalid | some drink | False |

So table 2 is very similar to table 1, the difference is that in table 2, I have, for an order, a row created for each product that was in that order.
Also, I have the IIM column, where if for an order there is at least one product where IIM = True, the entire order is considered IIM = True

Here comes my question/problem:

I want, in a single query, to get the number of orders where:

- store_id = 25
- store_id = 25 and IIM = True
- store_Id excluding store_Id 1,2,3
- store_id excluding 1,2,3 and IIM = True

(Only taking into account valid orders)

To achieve this, I did this:

```
SELECT
    yearmonth,
    date_,
    SUM(cant_store_25) AS cant_store_25,
    SUM(cant_store_25_iim) AS cant_store_25_iim,
    SUM(cant_store_plus) AS cant_store_plus,
    SUM(cant_store_plus_iim) AS cant_store_plus_iim
FROM
    (SELECT
        yearmonth,
        date_,
        order_,
        MAX(cant_store_25) AS cant_store_25,
        MAX(cant_store_25_iim) AS cant_store_25_iim,
        MAX(cant_store_plus) AS cant_store_plus,
        MAX(cant_store_plus_iim) AS cant_store_plus_iim
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            t1.Order_Number AS order_,
            t1.Order_Date::DATE AS date_,
            YEAR(t1.Order_Date::DATE) * 100 + MONTH(t1.Order_Date::DATE) AS yearmonth,
            CASE WHEN t1.Store_ID = 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cant_store_25,
            CASE WHEN t1.Store_ID = 25 AND IIM = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cant_store_25_iim,
            CASE WHEN t1.Store_ID NOT IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cant_store_plus,
            CASE WHEN t1.Store_ID NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND IIM THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS cant_store_plus_iim,
            MAX(IIM) AS IIM_
        FROM
            Table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN
            Table2 t2 ON t1.Customer_ID = t2.Customer_ID AND t1.Order_Number = t2.Order_Number
        WHERE
            t1.Is_Valid = 'Valid'
        GROUP BY
            t1.Order_Number, date_, yearmonth, t1.Store_ID, IIM)
    GROUP BY
        1, 2, 3)
WHERE
    yearmonth = 202208
GROUP BY
    1, 2;
```

So is there a better way to achieve this? My database is small so this query works for me, but maybe I can improve several things to make it more efficient. Honestly, I'm new and I want to learn just in case in the future I have to work with larger databases :)

I don't know if it's relevant, but I use Snowflake

Thanks!

Comment: you don't need "select distinct" when using "group by". group by (by itself) produces distinct rows

Comment: @PaulMaxwell Yes, I know but I keep making the same mistake. I have to get out of the habit of using the distinct. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to check but the first query and subquery can be done with something simpler like the following:

```
SELECT t1.Order_Number AS order_,
       t1.Order_Date::DATE AS date_,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Store_ID = 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cant_store_25,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Store_ID = 25 AND IIM = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cant_store_25_iim,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Store_ID NOT IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cant_store_plus,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t1.Store_ID NOT IN (1, 2, 3) AND IIM THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cant_store_plus_iim
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
    ON t1.Customer_ID = t2.Customer_ID 
    AND t1.Order_Number = t2.Order_Number
WHERE t1.Is_Valid = 'Valid'
    AND YEAR(t1.Order_Date::DATE) = 2022
    AND MONTH(t1.Order_Date::DATE) = 8
GROUP BY t1.Order_Number
        ,date_
```

and then the outer one will just `SUM` the data. The main idea is that you can calculate the conditions for each order earlies applying the `MAX` function. The good part is we do not need a `DISTINCT` as we are grouping.

Also, I have remove `MAX(IIM) AS IIM_` as it is not used, and add the year-month filtering earlier. As you are filtering for particular year-month, there is no point to calculate all the data and then get only its.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the last two selects, where I use the max function to count the 1's and then add them, so it's not that bad?

Comment: I believe not :-)